# Turning off default flash behavior in iOS Xam.Plugin.Media

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I turn off flash by default? In iOS, the camera flash is always activated. Android's default flash behavior is off so I have no problem with that.

Comment: Did you try using [Xamarin Essentials Flashlight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/flashlight?tabs=android) plugin ?

Comment: This is not possible with the default plugin behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this option is not available so far. I see the documentation and the code but didn't find.

There is also a open issue there in GitHub [Set camera flash default](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/380). In this discussion, the author seems still working on this feature but haven't completed.

To solve this problem,

1. You can overwrite the plugin code and turn off flash by default.

   Refer :[flashlight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/flashlight?tabs=ios)
2. You can use this plugin  https://github.com/kphillpotts/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Lamp